# How do I compare object value with a JQuery ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following object:

```
{
    builders: [
        {
            name: "Branches > Build",
            slaves: [
                "slave-01.local"
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "Branches > Build1",
            slaves: [
                "slave-02.local"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to update the html table td if their parent tr id matches the name attribute of the json.

```
<table>
  <tr id="Branches > Build" class="odd">
    <td>
      value of slaves of Branches > Build should be here
    </td>
  <tr id="Branches > Build1" class="even">
    value of slaves of Branches > Build1 should be here
    <td>
    </td>
<table>
```

How do I achieve this? I'm using jquery.

Btw. I can't get id's with no spaces so it must work with that.

Comment: You id is invalid change it as `id="Branches_Build1"` from `id="Branches > Build1"`

Comment: I know but I'm in a situation where i can't get that right now.

Comment: Your JSON is not valid JSON. Are you use it is JSON and not just a JavaScript object?

Comment: What are you stuck on here?  Looping over the array?  Finding the elements?  Updating the text?

Comment: Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UaLNy/, this is the one you have expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't change the id to a valid id, you can use Attribute-selectors `[id=""]`

```
var obj = "the jsonfile";
var objBuilder = obj.builders;
for (var key in obj) {
    var item = $('[id="' + obj[key].name + '"]')
    if (item.length) {
        item.find('td').text(obj[key].slaves);
    }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/YTdLL/) fixed html markup aswell

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
    var json = {
        builders: [
            {
                name: "Branches > Build",
                slaves: [
                    "slave-01.local"
                ]
            },
            {
                name: "Branches > Build1",
                slaves: [
                    "slave-02.local"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }

    $("table tr").each(function(index, obj){

        console.log(index+obj.id + json.builders[0].name);

        if(obj.id == json.builders[0].name){

            $(this).find('td').html('test');
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [basic types](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/types.html#type-name)

```
ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number
 of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods   (".").

IDREF and IDREFS are references to ID tokens defined by other attributes. IDREF is a single token and IDREFS is a space-separated list of tokens.

NUMBER tokens must contain at least one digit ([0-9]).
```

So you probably have to find a better way to solve it and use proper IDs. I suggest you to go for javascript frameworks such as ["Aungular"](http://angularjs.org/) that will make your job simpler and you can do much more things using it.